# Not able to set value to a variable by calling it inside a method

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

I want to set a boolean execute as true by passing it into a method set_Execute.Can someone help on solving this?

Here is code:

```
 public boolean canExecute(){
    boolean execute=false;
    set_Execute(execute);
    log("can execute"+execute); //it is going inside method set_Execute but it is always printing execute as false
    return execute;
    }

    private boolean set_Execute(boolean setExecute){
    return setExecute=true;
    }
```

Comment: @ritesht93 That will make absolutely no difference. `Boolean` is immutable.

Comment: No i went thru that post but didnt get precise response and also it talks abt passing by reference or value.mine is diferent

Comment: It's not.  It's exactly the same.

Comment: Can u help me with this problem  then?

Comment: I already have. The duplicate linked explains exactly what is going on here.

Comment: Straight forward answer please?

Comment: Java is pass by value.

Answer (score 1):

you should set back the value to execute like below.

```
execute = set_Execute(execute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Booleans in Java are immutable wrappers so they can't be set. What you can do is use an `AtomicBoolean` if you want to be able to edit the inner value from within a method.

```
public boolean canExecute(){
    AtomicBoolean execute = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    set_Execute(execute);
    log("can execute" + execute.get());
    return execute.get();
}

private void set_Execute(AtomicBoolean setExecute) {
    setExecute.set(true);
}
```

Comment: Please don't confound immutability and variable assignment. Their example doesn't fail because anything is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want directly because, as Pillar explained, Java passes variables by value, not by reference. So a change to method parameter never passes back to the caller.

A reference to an instance of a class is also passed by value, but the reference still points to the same instance as the one that the caller sees, so a good solution is to encapsulate your execute flag in a class and operate on an instance of it.
That way you can change the value inside the instance.

In your case your flag represents a permission so it makes sense to create a class `Permission`.

I've left the rest of the code the same, but depending on the overall architecture of your application, it probably makes sense to make the `set_Execute` method into the `Permission` class as well.

```
public class Permission {
    private boolean allowed;

    public void setAllowed(boolean allowed) {
        this.allowed = allowed;
    }

    // Add getAllowed and toString methods
}
```

```
public Permission canExecute(){
    Permission execute = new Permission();
    set_Execute(execute);
    log("can execute"+execute); //it is going inside method set_Execute but it is always printing execute as false
    return execute;
}

private void set_Execute(Permission setExecute){
    setExecute.setAllowed(true);
}
```